# 'PersonForm' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to pass string to a hidden field `scenario` of a form whose data is stored in a database. The goal is to be able to retrieve extra information on client side without having it as another field of the form.
I am getting `'PersonForm' object has no attribute 'as_widget'` error.

**This is my Model:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    region           = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    industry         = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    uuid             = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    scenario         = models.ForeignKey(Scenario,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.uuid)
```

**My Form**

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Person

        scenario   = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
        fields     = ['industry', 'region','scenario']
```

**My View**

```
def personforms(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filled_form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        if filled_form.is_valid():
            created_person    = filled_form.save()
            #DEBUG
            print(filled_form.cleaned_data['scenario'])

            created_person_pk = created_person.id
            filled_form      = PersonForm()
            return redirect('/scenariopage', {'persons':persons})
        else:
            created_person_pk = None
        return render(request, 'core/scenario-landing-page.html', {'personform':filled_form, 'created_person_pk':created_person_pk})
    else:
        form = PersonForm()
        return render(request, 'core/scenario-landing-page.html', {'personform':form})
```

**And my template**

```
 <form action="{% url 'personform' %}" method="post" class="custom-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_field personform class="form-control" %}
    {% render_field personform.scenario class="form-control form-control-sm" value='{{ scenario.name }}' %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn color-btn" value="Go to Scenario page" data-dismiss="gallery-item"/>
</form>
```

Questions I have:

I have no Error message. But debug print is indicating that `filled_form.is_valid():` seems to be invalid.
And this line in the View never print result:

`#DEBUG
 print(filled_form.cleaned_data['scenario'])`

- What I am doing wrong?
- How could I possibly pass the data to the field `scenario`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I have just updated the message. I dont have error message per se, but f `filled_form.is_valid()` in the view is  invalid.

Comment: But why are you creating a form if you are not calling it ?????? Just say `{{personform}}` in the template and make your attributes in the `forms.py`, use widgets

Comment: @Moha369  isn`t the loop in `{% for field in personform %}` doing just that?

Comment: also how do you pass `field.scenario value='{{ scenario.name }}` otherwise?

Comment: As i said, just say {{personform}} in the template and then call scenario in the widgets, read more about widgets, p.s there is no loop

Comment: I will provide an answer once i get to a computer

Comment: Your line `filled_form = PersonForm()` is puzzling to me. Why initialise a new form object, overwriting the one containing request.POST data? Also, do you have the hidden CharField form element defined inside the Form Meta, as shown in 'My Form' above? I don't believe an action form element can be a Meta option in this way.